# Integral definition of e

Tags: integration, definition, exponential-function

I know that $e$ can be defined via a convergent series: $$ e = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {1\over n!}$$

Or as a limit: $$ e = \lim_{n \to \infty} { \left(1 + {1 \over n}\right)^n }$$

Or as the value which satisfies the condition:

> For any real number $x$, $f(x) = {df\over{dx}}$

Is there an integral definition of $e$ ?

Something like: $$e = \int_0^\infty ...$$

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\Big(\frac{1}{x}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x}(1+\sin(t))^{1/t}dt\Big)$

Comment: Your derivative definition is a little bit dodgy. If $\mathrm{f}(x) = \mathrm{f}'(x)$ then $\mathrm{f}(x) = k\mathrm{e}^x$, where $k$ is any real number (the zero function, i.e. $k=0$, satisfies the ODE!). You need to apply some initial conditions, e.g. $\mathrm{e}$ is given by the value $\mathrm{f}(1)$ when $\mathrm{f}(x) = \mathrm{f}'(x)$, subject to the condition $\mathrm{f}(0)=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you accept $\displaystyle e = \int_0^\infty \frac1{\lfloor x\rfloor!} \,dx$?

Comment: Is that correct? It just keeps spitting it back out on my TI-89.

Comment: It's correct, but it's not very interesting — it's just $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{n!}$ in a thin disguise.

Comment: Well it's what I was looking for. Don't know why I didn't get this earlier.

Comment: What scenario exactly is this answer useful in?

Answer (score 2):

$\int_1^x \frac{1}t dt = 1$ so $e$ is the unique $x$.

Comment: doesn't answer the question IMO...

Comment: Shouldnt you get $\ln x$?

Comment: $e$ is the unique $x$ which satisfy the equation

Comment: @fish.frog Shush.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's worth pointing out the link between the examples you proffered.

Note $e^t$ is the solution to the differential equation $dx/dt = x, x(0) = 1$. Thus, $x(1) = e$.

Now, try to approximate the solution to this ODE using the forward Euler method with step size $1/h$ to estimate $x(1)$. The first step yields $x(1/h) \approx x(0) + (1/h)x(0) = (1 + 1/h)x(0) = 1 + 1/h$. The second step yields $x(2/h) \approx x(1/h) + (1/h)(x(1/h) = (1+1/h)x(1/h) = (1+1/h)^2$. Taking $h$ steps yields $x(1) \approx (1 + 1/h)^h$. Using consistent approximations results, you get that, as the step size $1/h$ goes to $0$, $x(1) \rightarrow e$.

Now, note that $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = \frac{d}{dt} \left( dx/dt \right) = \frac{d}{dt} x$. (This follows just by plugging in the equality $dx/dt = x$.) Inducting, we get that $\frac{d^nx}{dt^n} = x$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and the convergent sum result is simply a direct application of Taylor's theorem.

Basically, my point is that these equivalent definitions are not coincidence, and hint at a lot of neat results.